# Generate new name for moved file to prevent overwriting?

Tags: files, rename, filenames, busybox

How can I generate a new name for a file if there's an existing file With that same name? In a Desktop environment a new name is generated my appending a number to the end of the file name, but how can this be  accomplished from the command line?

I'm using the Android operating system with Busybox.

Comment: Can you expand you Q to specify in what capacity you want to make these files with respect to android? Java? What tooling do you have, busybox? Or just vanilla android?

Comment: @user slm I am going to use it for backing up the files contained in the download folder on my tablet, the program sorts the files based on the extension into there respective folders, i have written a python script that does this, but the program is slow and also overwrites a file if it has the same name. I am in the process of rewriting the program into bash, generating a new name is the part that i was struggling with.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Do you have access then to a version of `mktemp`?

Comment: @user slm I have busybox installed and it is included, but if i do a system call from a program `mktemp` will not work.

Comment: Doesn't work with some kind of error? Also where are you making this system call from? Python?

Comment: @user i am calling it from python but i also tried to call the function from C and it will say `/system/bin/sh: mktemp: not found`

Comment: If you do a `echo $PATH` in that system command you can see what your `$PATH` is set to. Confirm that `mktemp`'s location matches the `$PATH`. You might need to just add its location.

Comment: @kylek I have updated my answer if `mktemp` not exists then it will append `source_copy` as file name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a POSIX shell, you can do this:

```
mv() {
        eval "DEST=\${$#}" #The destination is the last positional parameter
        if [ -e "$DEST" ] && ! [ -d "$DEST" ];then
                PREFIX=${DEST%.*}
                COUNT=1
                EXT=${DEST##*.}
                args= i=1
                while [ $i -lt $# ]; do args="$args \"\${$i}\"" i=$((i+1)); done
                DEST="$NAME-"$(printf "%03d" $COUNT)".$EXT"
                while [ -e "$DEST" ];do
                    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
                    DEST="$NAME-"$(printf "%03d" $COUNT)".$EXT"
                done
                eval "command mv $args \"\$DEST\""
        else
                command mv "$@"
        fi
}
```

**How to use this**

This is a function so save it in your `~/.bashrc` and call it as you would the normal `mv`.

**What this does**

- Stores the path to the original `mv` executable in the `MV` variable
- Gets the last argument it was called with into the variable `DEST`
- If `DEST` exists and is not a directory, this function assumes that your rename is trying to clobber a file
- It then extracts the final name's prefix (anything before the final `.`, which marks the extension), the extension (anything after the final `.`), the count (if any; anything in the prefix after the final `-`).
- The extracted count is set to zero if no count was found otherwise, it's set to the count found in the previous step.
- The current count is incremented
- The function then calls itself with all the original arguments (switches + file names) minus the last one and adds the new file name instead of the last argument in the original call. The new name is the old name but with a 3 digit counter (with zero-stuffing) added before the extension.
- The function is recursive because if you were saying `mv a.txt b.txt` it will first try `mv a.txt b-001.txt`. This next `mv` call must also be the function itself because if `b-001.txt` also exists, we want to keep incrementing the counter until we find a new file name that doesn't exist.
- If the final argument doesn't exist or is a directory, the original `mv` executable is called with your original arguments.

**Caveats**

- The number of times you can repeatedly try to clobber an existing file depends on the length of the counter (999 times in this case). You may choose a number of digits that encompasses the inode limit on your filesystem to ensure that this will work for as long as you're able to create files.
- If you try to clobber a file whose name is similar to `foo-001.txt`, it will be moved to `foo-001-001.txt`.

**Notes**

- To change the naming pattern, change the `3` in the `printf` statement to whatever you like.
- This code has been tested
- This is very simplistic and I'm sure there will be edge cases where it fails miserably. I'm happy to try and fix them for you if you find any. In the meantime, don't try this on a production machine.

Comment: same mind here :P

Comment: @RahulPatil Except I'm attempting to duplicate the GUI behavior.

Comment: that's great, I haven't used GUI yet.

Comment: it's overwriting the destination file if it exits , I have tested http://paste.ubuntu.com/6071897/

Comment: @RahulPatil Not sure what you're saying: in your example, it identified that `/tmp` is an existent directory and called `/bin/mv file1 /tmp` I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: file1 is exits in /tmp/

Comment: @RahulPatil Yes and if you try `/bin/mv file1 /tmp`, you get:
`/bin/mv: 'file1' and '/tmp/file1' are the same file` so nothing gets clobbered.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks a lot for your edit. One thing I don't get though: why did you remove the recursion? If `b.txt` and `b-001.txt` exist, this will rename `a.txt` to `b-001-001.txt`, no?

Comment: @JosephR. I wasn't paying attention, sorry.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the correction. May I ask why you preferred to use `eval` instead of calling `mv` directly?

Comment: @JosephR. Due to the lack of arrays, there is no direct way to express “all the arguments except the last one”. What I do here is to build a string `"${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}"` (this one is when there are 5 arguments), which the shell then interprets via `eval` to build the desired command line.

Comment: @Gilles but by the end of the `whole` loop, the `args` and `DEST` variables should be already built and you can say `mv $args "$DEST"`, no?

Comment: @JosephR. No: `args` contains `"${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}"`, it doesn't contain the parameter values. That wouldn't be possible because you can't stuff a list of parameters into a single string. The variable `args` always ends up having the same value, but it needs to be used in each recursive call, or else the structure has to change. I think this would be clearer if the function was written as a loop that changes `DEST`, with a final call to the `mv` command after the loop, instead of using recursion which requires reassembling the parameters each time.

Comment: @Gilles Got it. Thanks. And I see what you mean by your suggestion. I'll implement it when I have time and post back here.

Comment: @Gilles Something like this, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I generally use the tool `mktemp` to create reliable temporary files. It defaults to creating files, but can also make directories too, through its `-d` switch.

#### Example

Here's how you can create some temporary names to files in your current directory.

```
$ mktemp somefile.XXXXX
somefile.kiDad

$ mktemp somefile.XXXX
somefile.MrSW

$ mktemp someotherfile.XXXXXXXXXXX
someotherfile.Um4aXKrt3lv
```

This will create the files for you.

#### References

- [mktemp man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen//mktemp.html)

Comment: No `mktemp` on android, but +1 from me anyway since this is a good answer to a good question, U&L wise.

Comment: @goldilocks - thank you for your kind words. It's always nice!

Comment: @goldilocks - do you know offhand if busybox is included? There's an implementation of mktemp in that, I do not know that much about android. http://code.google.com/p/abb/source/browse/mktemp.c?name=upstream/0_60_1

Comment: Looks like busybox on android requires the device be rooted (jailbroken).  The native shell is `/system/bin/sh` and seems to be `sh` compatible -- constructs like `if [ -w $file ]` work, `mv` and `rename` are available -- so a script to do this just with built-ins should work there.

Comment: @goldilocks - thanks for checking. What are you looking in to find this out? I'd like to get my feet wet with android but don't want to have a phone/device.

Comment: I have an ASUS transformer, but even with the keyboard it's not something I like to sit and code on much (coding *for* I like). The terminal emulator is 3rd party and I think to chmod stuff that way you'd need to root it as well (heh-heh -- the line editor I have saves stuff as a different user == I can write scripts but not execute them).  Ostensibly I'm developing normal user stuff for it, so I'm avoiding the jailbroken path.  One way or another I'm sure this could be made to work tho.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to Joseph R's script which has none of the caveats!  It will append a numerical suffix to a path name (the path can be a directory or a file), incrementing the suffix value until one is found which does not already exist.  Other utilities such as `logrotate` use a similar pattern, but rotate all existing copies so that the new one always has '0' for a suffix.  Since this isn't a rotation in that sense, I'll call it `dotmv`.  Just remember that `file.0` will be the *oldest* copy.

For example:

```
dotmv somefile.txt
```

Renames `somefile.txt` `somefile.txt.0`, unless the latter exists, in which case it will be `somefile.txt.1`, and so on.  You can list more than one file (`dotmv this that "the other thing"` etc.), all of them will be dot-moved.

I believe this is POSIX compliant -- it runs with `set -o posix` on bash (but that is a dubious test).  I also tested with the android (jelly bean 4.2.1) shell, and it works there.  However, on android you will need to change the shebang as indicated or run it `sh dotmv` -- which you will anyway unless you have a rooted device, because there is no way to make a script executable otherwise.  Changing the shebang will allow you to use `exec dotmv`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# On android change that to /system/bin/sh.

# Validate arguments
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "A list of one or more paths is required."
    exit 1
fi

# Checks if a path exists and can be moved.
checkPath () {
    if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
        echo "'$1' does not exist."
        return 1;
    fi
    if [ ! -w "$1" ]; then
        echo "Cannot move '$1', permission denied."
        return 1;
    fi
    return 0;
}

# Finds a new path with numerical suffix.
getName () {
    suf=0;
    while [ -e "$1.$suf" ]
        do let suf+=1
    done
    Dest=$1.$suf
}

# Loop through arguments -- use quotes to allow spaces in paths.
while (($#)); do
    Src=$1
    Dest=$1
    shift
    checkPath "$Src"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        getName "$Src"
        mv "$Src" "$Dest"
    fi
done
```

Hopefully the logic here is very straight-forward. This could be implemented in python, C, or any other turing complete procedural language with file I/O.